# Language support for Google Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I'd like to perform a partial text / phrase search against a Datastore record field using Ruby.

I've figured out how to do it with a conditional constraint using >= <"\ufffd" condition, but that only works from the beginning of the field.

This works; querying for "Ener" returns "Energizer AA Batteries" but querying for "AA" does not return the same.

In the docs for the Python Google Client's Search API, it documents the ability to manually create indexes which allow for both atomic and partial word searches.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/ says:

> Tokenizing string fields When an HTML or text field is indexed, its
>   contents are tokenized. The string is split into tokens wherever
>   whitespace or special characters (punctuation marks, hash sign, etc.)
>   appear. The index will include an entry for each token. This enables
>   you to search for keywords and phrases comprising only part of a
>   field's value. For instance, a search for "dark" will match a document
>   with a text field containing the string "it was a dark and stormy
>   night", and a search for "time" will match a document with a text
>   field containing the string "this is a real-time system".

In the docs for Ruby and PHP, I cannot find such an API reference to enable me to do the same thing.  Is it possible to perform this type of query in Ruby / PHP with Cloud Datastore?

If so, can you point me to the docs, and if not, is there a workaround, for example, create indexes with the Python Search API, and then configure the PHP/Ruby client to execute it's queries against those indexes?

Comment: The documentation you quote does not talk about partial word searches - only complete tokens.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin but although it tokenizes by words, if I search for "AA" it should come up with "Energizer AA Batteries." That would be a good start.

Comment: Datastore does not allow for partial word searches. Consider using the search api.

Comment: This is my PHP library for using the Python search API https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-search